# Validate text using Jeditable in div <div> or Paragraph <P>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I want to validate the text/data before submitting to the server. Here is my div

```
<div class="edit" id="editme">edit me</div>
```

So i want to validate the data in div and then submit it. I tried something like this,

```
    $('.edit').editable("${g.createLink(controller: 'comment', action:'editCommentForDocument')}",{
        event: 'dblclick',
        type      : 'autogrow',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
        submit    : 'OK',
        indicator : '<img src="../images/spinner.gif">',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
        onblur    : ignore,
        submitdata : function(value, settings){
            if(value.trim() == ''){
                alert('empty');
            }

        },
        data : function(value, settings){
            if(value.trim() == ''){
                alert('empty');
            }
        },
        edit: {
            lineHeight : 12,
            minHeight  : 32
        }

    });


});
```

I even tried using onsubmit inside jeditable block-

```
    onsubmit: function(settings, td) {
          var input = $(td).find('input');
          alert(input)   
     }
```

Nothing is working. Help please.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: onsubmit works for me. Just return false if it fails validation. Can you first make sure your save link works and jeditable is enabled for the element. BTW you have extra "});" at the end that are not needed.